# How to install Open CV in Ubuntu 12.04 without compiling from source?

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu-12.04

I tried installing Open CV using the following command on my Ubuntu 12.04

```
sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev
```

When I try to `import opencv` in python, it shows the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named cv2
```

Is there a way to install Open CV without compiling from source?

Answer (score 3):

Try installing it this way:

1. Download this [opencv_install.sh](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jayrambhia/Install-OpenCV/master/Ubuntu/opencv_install.sh) script.
2. Make the script executable by running the following command in your command line.

   `chmod +x open_install.sh`

   You must be in the directory where this script is downloaded.
3. Run the script.

   `./opencv_install.sh`

   This will install opencv

Comment: There seems to be a lot more to it than just downloading that file

Answer (score 0):

You just installed `libopencv-dev` and trying call python module. You also need to install python bindings of opencv.

```
sudo apt-get install python-opencv
```

You might need to install numpy and other requirements.